# MySQL avoid duplicate entries in CurrentTimeStamp

Tags: mysql, sql

when i trying to insert large set of rows using `sql` query directly into database.

```
INSERT INTO `table1`(`id1`, `id2`, `id3`) 
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,id4, id5 FROM table2
```

> Duplicate entry '2015-02-03 20:49:59' for key 'PRIMARY'

It is because two rows trying add same time-stamp as their primary key. In java we can check uniqueness through maintaining a variable. How to ensure this uniqueness while directly inserting in mysql database

Comment: Don't use a timestamp for primary key, use a sequence value (or whatever it's called by MySQL.)

Comment: This is exactly why `TimeStamp` or `DateTime` columns make horrible primary keys...

Comment: If you want to now the timestamp of the inserted row, you can put a column `id` autoincrement as PK, for example

Answer (score 3):

Timestamp/DateTime should never be used for any primary key the first issue being you can insert more than 1 record in second, leading to duplicate primary keys.

Use and integer with auto increment for your primary key then create a timestamp/Datetime and create an index on the column.